# How to send select value to php using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i m trying to passe the value of the selected item from a select tag using ajax for that :
here it is the select tag(it is not in a form):

```
                 <select class="select" id="select" >
                 </select>
```

here it is the code that fill the select from the database using php:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   <?php foreach ($espace_ids as $row ) {?>

   $('#select').append('<option value="<?php echo $row['espace_id']; ?>"><? php echo $row['nom']; ?></option>'); 

   <?php }?>  });
```

for sending data from the actual page to dashbored.php,here it is the code:

```
   $("#select").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "<?php //echo base_url(); ?>index.php?directeur/dashboard ?>",
            data: espace_id: $("#select").val(),
            success: function( data ) {
                alert( data );
            }

        });
```

well i retrieve the value sent with :

```
$espace_id=$_POST['espace_id'];
```

the probleme that it display : undefined refrence to espace_id in dashboard.php.
well , the pupose is to load the espace info from the database according to the espace selected by the user.each time the user select an option i should load the appropiate info related to the espace selected.
i wish that you gonna help me.
thanks

Comment: `<?php //echo base_url(); ?>index.php?directeur/dashboard ?>` is malformed php. Change to just `url: "index.php?directeur/dashboard",`

Comment: Not to mention the javascript is also wrong.

Comment: How is any of this code working at all? I can't even decipher the actual thing that you're asking for help with here.

Comment: Your data must be in object format. Use curly brace to enclose them like this, { espace_id: $("#select").val() }

Comment: @Sherif where is the problem !!

Comment: @Sherif my problem is that i can't pass the value of the selected option using ajax !!!

Comment: In ajax data should be with braces:
data: { espace_id: $("#select").val() },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following example to get espace id in `index.php`.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#select').on('change', function () 
    {
        if ($('#select').val() === null) {              
            alert("Error");
        }
        else
        {
            var selectedValue = $('#select').val();

            $.ajax
            ({
                url: 'index.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'espace_id=' + selectedValue,
                success: function(response) 
                {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**on index.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['espace_id']) && !empty($_POST['espace_id']))
{
  // do whatever you want to do here!!
}
```

Comment: check at multiple stages. (1) - check if ajax request is firing by using alert immediately after $.ajax like alert(selectedValue); (2) - use var_dump($_POST); in top of your PHP script to get overview what all fields are actually posted to script. by using this you'll get fair idea where the problem is. code shared by me should work without any error. use suggestions just explained in it. you'll get to know whats actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to keep it lighter than Jquery you could do something like this:

```
<select onchange="livesearch(this.value)"><option></option></select>
<script> 
function livesearch(id){ 
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlhttp.open("GET","url?id="+id, false); xmlhttp.send(null); document.getElementById("searchresults").value=xmlhttp.responseText; } 
</script>
```

Comment: actually i didn't understand why did you put xmlhttp.send(null);